# codenameone reference components from another function

Tags: codenameone

I have created a register form (not using the designer).

On the form I have created numerous text fields as well as a button with ...

```
    Button btnRegister = new Button();
    btnRegister.setName("btnRegister");
    btnRegister.setText("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            frmRegister_btnRegister(f);
        }
    });
    f.addComponent(btnRegister);
```

My question is how do I reference the textfields in the function being called from the button action listener. Specifically I am trying to set up arguments to use for a network call using addArgument. When I used the designer I used find(ComponentName) but that is not available anymore.

```
private void frmRegister_btnRegister(Form f) {
    // register new user
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest(); 
    r.setUrl(sUrlWebSvc);
    r.setPost(true);

    r.addArgument("Rest", "1");          // restaurant code
    r.addArgument("Req", "Register");    // R = register


    //r.addArgument("first_name", findTxtUsertName(c).getText());

    // show spinning dialog while connecting
    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
    r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
    //System.out.println(r.getResponseData());      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its defined just above this line:

```
Button btnRegister = new Button();
```

As:

```
TextField txt =....
```

Just change it to:

```
final TextField txt =....
```

And then you can pass it (or its getText() string value) to:

```
btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        frmRegister_btnRegister(f, txt);
    }
});
```

Naturally you will need to update the signature of `frmRegister_btnRegister` to accept a text field or a string.

Comment: Due to the number of fields and expecting to use this in other areas of my application, I was hoping that passing the form to the function being called in actionPerformed would allow me to access all of the components on the form. I am looking to get the text value of several fields to pass to a web svc. Is there no corresponding method such as the findComponentName I was using when I used the designer to create the form?

Comment: No, that is not a method of form its a method of the UIBuilder. The name is explicitly set using setName() and the GUI builder caches components in the client properties. You would end up writing far more code to get this to work.
That is why we recommend using the GUI builder since it hides a lot of grunt work.